# D7 jquery dropdown menu categorized/ordered by content type and taxonomy

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, javascript, navigation

In D7 I want to create a jquery dropdown menu categorized/ordered by content type (first level) and (if content type has taxnonomy tags) taxonomy via views.

What is the best approach? thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now use custom menu items and the modules 'Taxonomy Menu' together with 'Nice Menu' and some custom jquery javascript.